# Loading files with names containing multiple variables (MATLAB)

Tags: string, matlab, numbers

I'm trying to load about 40 files into MATLAB, all of who's names and locations are the same apart from 2 variable pieces. They each contain 5000 datapoints, which I want to combine into 1 single vector.
They are HDF5 files, so I also have to specify the path inside the file, the name of which contains these variables too.

An example of loading one of these files would be

```
ROdata = double(h5read('directories\010340text2\010340text2.hdf5','/othertext2'));
```

Here, the variables would be 010340 and 2. So the general form is something like (n terms of x and y)

```
ROdata = double(h5read('directories\xtexty\xtexty.hdf5','/othertexty'));
```

Both x and y I have in an array already loaded into MATLAB.

From this point, I'm pretty clueless. I suppose num2str comes in somewhere, but I've tried a few things (like in the video http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/07/02/advanced-loading-files-using-their-names-for-variable-names/) but that doesn't work, as the variable part is inside the text, not at the end.

I could of course do so manually, but these 40 are from a series of around 300, so that'll be a lot of writing.

Comment: please include the pattern for how the two variables change (and their range).

Comment: There's no real pattern for x. It's 010307, 010323, 010340 for example, and even the numbers change now and then. They refer to a time. y is simply 0 to 24.

Comment: I think you should have a look at the `dir` function using wildcards: `filenames = dir('directories\*text*\*text*.hdf5');`

Comment: Some general advice: First create all the strings, only then try to load them. This way it should be much easier to try stuff out.

Comment: @Dan I don't think the `dir` command can accept wildcards in folder names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
ROdata = double(h5read( ... 
  sprintf( 'directories/%06dtext%d/%06dtext%d.hdf5', 010340, 2, 010340, 2 ), ...
  sprintf( '/othertext%d', 2 ) ));

%# or more general:
x = 010340;
y = 2;
ROdata = double(h5read( ...
  sprintf( 'directories/%06dtext%d/%06dtext%d.hdf5', x, y, x, y ), ...
  sprintf( '/othertext%d', y ) ));

%# or even more general:
%# assume X is your array containing elements x, Y for y elements

ROdata = cell{ numel(X), 1 };
for ii=1:numel(X)
  ROdata{ii} = double(h5read( ...
    sprintf( 'directories/%06dtext%d/%06dtext%d.hdf5', X(ii), Y(ii), X(ii), Y(ii) ), ...
    sprintf( '/othertext%d', Y(ii) ) ));
end
```

Have a look at the [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) function, it's quite neat.

In order for this to work, you need to use forward slashes, as backslahes act as escape characters. Another possibility would be to use `'\\'`, but `'/'` is more readable and works as well.

Since the numbers in `X` may contain leading zeros: `%06d` adds zero padding such that the inserted number will always be 6 digits long.

Comment: Hm, I've tried a few times to make sure I wasn't messing up somewhere, but I'm getting Error using fclose
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in h5read (line 58)
fclose(fid);

Comment: Ok I found two issues:
1. You need to use forward slashes
2. You need to take care of the zero padding (for example in 010340). Are these values always of the same length?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was about to post what went wrong, but the forward slashes in the directory name fix it. It still goes wrong after that, as you're right about the 0 padding. The values are always the same length, 6 numbers, but they don't always start with a 0. Most of them do though, so if it's hard to cater to both cases lets just stick to the ones starting with a 0!

Comment: Cool! No, you can actually solve this nicely, let me find the correct padding function, I'll update the answer accordingly!

Comment: Thank you very much! Just adding a 0 before the %d also works I suppose, but then I do run into an issue for those not starting with a 0.

Comment: %06d adds zero padding such that the inserted number will always be 6 digits long.

Answer (score 1):

What about using string concatenation?

```
ROdata = double(h5read(['directories\xtexty\' num2str(x) 'xtexty.hdf5'],['/othertexty' num2str(y)]));
```